# Hotkeys override

Tags: c#, c++, keyboard-shortcuts, policy, hotkeys

Difficult question. The answer is probably no, if all I found in the Intertubes is right, but it is worth a try. I need to override the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> combinations. It would be good to be able to override the <kbd>Win</kbd> key combinations, but I have a low level hook that does such, I only wish I didn't need it. If I can manage to block the start menu and the task manager entirely by policy, the overrides will no longer be needed but I couldn't find the correct policy to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can override <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> (I just tried in AutoHotkey, it works), but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>, no more than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.

So using policies is probably the way to go... No experience in this field, I fear.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes here looking for a non-AutoHotKey, here is a c# way.

It is possible to do this using a keyboard hook. A good hook class for this can be found on this  [CodeProject Article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/7294/processing-global-mouse-and-keyboard-hooks-in-c)

Using the below code will prevent the <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd> from occurring. You can use this to override whichever keys you'd like.

This will even override hotkeys which you added via `RegisterHotKey` Win API.

Once you have those classes in your project you can add handlers to the static `HookManager` class like below.

```
//It's worth noting here that if you subscribe to the Key_Press event then it will break the international accent keys.
HookManager.KeyPress += HookManager_KeyPress;
HookManager.KeyDown += HookManager_KeyDown;
HookManager.KeyUp += HookManager_KeyUp;
```

You can also add mouse events, but for simplicity I'm just showing the keyboard hook.

I've also created a generic list so that I know which keys are currently down and I remove those keys from the list on the `KeyUp` event.

```
public static List<Keys> keysDown = new List<Keys>();
private static void HookManager_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Used for overriding the Windows default hotkeys
            if(keysDown.Contains(e.KeyCode) == false)
            {
                keysDown.Add(e.KeyCode);
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && WIN())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                //Do what you want when this key combination is pressed
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && WIN())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                //Do what you want when this key combination is pressed
            }

        }

        private static void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Used for overriding the Windows default hotkeys
            while(keysDown.Contains(e.KeyCode))
            {
                keysDown.Remove(e.KeyCode);
            }
        }

        private static void HookManager_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            //Used for overriding the Windows default hotkeys

        }

        public static bool CTRL()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.LControlKey) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.RControlKey) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.Control) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.ControlKey))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool SHIFT()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.RShiftKey) ||
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.Shift) ||
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.ShiftKey))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool WIN()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.LWin) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.RWin))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool ALT()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.Alt))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

So you need do override Hotkeys on your application?
Then the answer is probably yes, how?
No idea, but if this(http://www.inchwest.com/mapkeyboard.aspx) program can, so can you

Comment: He does by using low level keyboard hooks. But those don't work with the CTRL+SHIFT+ESC and CTRL+ESC combinations.